# Sort Weaviate results based on number field

Tags: weaviate

We are using Weaviate to serve e-commerce results.

Our Weaviate database stores all the products we sell.

Based on the customer and the search term we create a vector and use this to query the database. This property is called `search_engine_query_vector`.

For example if a customer has a habit of buying expensive products and searches for "TV" the system will most likely create a vector which is "closer" to the more expensive TVs in the database. So their first page of results is the most expensive TVs.

While this works well 99% of the time we also want ppl to be able to sort based on price.

For this we will send a query to Weaviate, where we only return products which are close to our vector(It is assumed this is all the TVs). like below:

```
client.query.get("Product", ["sku", "responseBody", "_additional { certainty }",
                                         "stores { ...on Store {storeId salesPrice additionalResponseBody}}"]).with_near_vector(
        {"vector": search_engine_query_vector, "similarity": TV_CUTOFF})
    .limit(10)
    .sort_base_on_price()
```

My question is there functionality in the api analogous to `sort_base_on_price`?
you can assume price is a number field in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great to hear you're working with Weaviate for an e-commerce solution.
[Weaviate added an initial version of sorting functionality in version 1.13](https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/releases/tag/v1.13.0)!

With the Weaviate version 1.13.0 we also released the python-client [v3.5.0](https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#version-3-5-0) that introduced this functionality too. You can find the needed method documentation for python [here](https://weaviate-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/weaviate.gql.html#weaviate.gql.get.GetBuilder.with_sort) or for other clients [here](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/graphql-references/get.html#sorting)!

For your use case, you could also try the following GraphQL query in the [Weaviate Console](https://console.semi.technology/):

```
{
  Get {
    Product(nearVector :{
      vector:[search_engine_query_vector],
      certainty: TV_CUTOFF
      } 
      sort:{
        order:desc,
        path:["price_field"]
      }
      limit: 10
    ) {
      sku
      responseBody
      stores { ...on Store {
        storeId 
        salesPrice 
        additionalResponseBody
      }
      _additional {
        certainty
      }
    }
  }
}
```